# Is this local diffeomorphism a global diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U$ be an open in $\mathbb R^n$, and let $f : U \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function such that a specific particular partial derivative $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_i}$ does not vanish in $U$. Define the function $g : U \to \mathbb R^n$ given by

$$g(x_1 \dots x_n) = (x_1 \dots x_{i-1}, f(x_1 \dots x_n), x_{i+1} \dots x_n)$$

The differential map $dg_p : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is invertible for every $p \in U$, hence $g$ is a local diffeomorphism. My question now is whether I can go further: Let $V$ be a connected component of $U$. Is the restriction $g \big \vert_V : V \to f(V)$ a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Any bijective local diffeomophism $g$ is a diffeomorphism. So in order to $g|_V : V \to g(V)$ to become diffeomorphism, $g|_V$ need to be injective on $V$. Which is true iff $f|_V$ is injective. But  think there are examples with $f$ is not injective everywhere.

Comment: @Sou Thanks. I understand everything except the last sentence. I don't see how $g \big \vert_V$ being injective implies that so is $f \big \vert_V$.

Comment: You right. Probably not.